# grails failed to display image in list view

Tags: grails

I want to display an image in list view of grails project

I have written an action in controller for displaying it in list

```
def showImage () {
    def testUnitInstance = TestUnit.get(params.testUnitId)
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg")
    response.setContentLength(testUnitInstance.image.size())
    response.outputStream << testUnitInstance.image
    response.outputStream.flush()
    }
```

in list view i have called that action

```
<img src="<g:createLink controller='testUnit' action='showImage' 
                    params='[testUnitId:testUnitInstance.id]'/>" height="14px" width="14px" alt="img"
                                    style="padding-left: 20px;"/>
```

but still the image is not displayed anyone suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Did you checked that your action is called correctly?

Comment: I could suggest you to use `${}` syntax there. Like `src="${createLink(controller:'testUnit'...)}"`.

Comment: @aiolos i have checked by printing hi in showImage action

Comment: ok, full example `src="${createLink(controller:'testUnit', action:'showImage', params:[testUnitId: testUnitInstance.id])}"`

Comment: But it's just suggestion to make it easier to read.

Comment: as about original question: what do you have as a result in gsp? valid link? or not? if valid link, what do you get if you'll open it in browser?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov no, i have completely included like <img src="${createLink (controller='testUnit' action='showImage' 
      params='[testUnitId:testUnitInstance.id]')}" height="14px" width="14px" alt="img"
          style="padding-left: 20px;"/> it shows  No signature of method: C__grails_workspace_GloSante_grails_app_views_testUnit_list_gsp.showImage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [[testUnitId:testUnitInstance.id]]

Comment: @Igor an empty square box with 14px height and width in the list view of TestUnit

Comment: Not `controller=''`, but `controller: ''`. Standard groovy syntax, not html syntax, it's groovy code.

Comment: i understand that you got square box. but i'm asking what you have in html code

Comment: <img src="/ProjectName/TestUnit/showPhoto?testUnitId=1" height="100" width="100">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36528/discussion-between-john-and-igor-artamonov)

Comment: If your html is correct and "hi" is printed on the console, then you have an error within your response. Debug your code within showImage()

Comment: @Igor my problem is i have updated my domain class by adding this as image variable, that is i have created a domain class with name and description as variable for that class after creation of view and controller for that i have added this image variable and regenerated its view i think that the reason why its not working can you suggest me a solution for this

Comment: So, what response do you have for url `/ProjectName/TestUnit/showPhoto?testUnitId=1`?

Comment: its working fine now i missed to insert enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag thanks to all